# Set "ignore ownership on this volume" for a disk image?

Tags: permission, disk-image

I have a mounted HFS+ disk image that I'd like to be equally accessible to all the user accounts on that system, in that they can all read and write files on it, create and delete files, and copy files into it that will be readable and writable by all the other users. This is all within a single system, and not over a network or using file sharing. Normally I'd handle this using "ignore ownership on this volume".

However, when I set it on a mounted disk image, it a) seems to have no effect, in that other user accounts still can't modify files, and b) it resets as soon as the disk image is reloaded.

Is this a limitation of disk images? Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Clarification please: one Mac with several users? One Mac acting as a file server to multiple Macs? IIRC, mounted disk images aren’t treated the same as physical or virtual disks, and this may be one limitation. Have you considered an external HDD or SSD instead?

Comment: It *may* depend on the image type, I'm really not sure. I have one expandable, encrypted image, set from one account to be 'ignore ownership' which is a) remembered each time it's mounted & b) shows the same permissions if I open it from another admin account. https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0mnk.png

Comment: @IconDaemon I've updated my question to clarify, but this is one mac with multiple users, and it's all within that single system, so no network activity or file sharing. I don't want to use (another!) an external drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oddly enough my drive is also HFS+ formatted and in a sparsebundle, so I'm not sure why it's working for you and not for me.

Comment: It's not something I really have much experience with, sorry. I just did it & it worked. You can see from the picture, this was quite some time ago & I just never questioned the precise structure or implications.